# Simple JS example of Singleton Pattern not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, singleton

I made a simple example of Singleton Pattern but it is giving blank objects in both cases. Please someone help?

```js
var a = ( function(){
 
  var instance = {};

  function init() {
     return {
      name: "rosy",
      age: 29,
      printName: function(){
        console.log(this.name)
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    getInstance: function(){
      if(!instance) {instance = init();}
      return instance;
    }
  }
})();

console.log(a.getInstance());
console.log(a.getInstance());
```

Comment: `if(!instance)` will always be `false` because `if({})` is `true`

Comment: All objects are truthy. So if you want `if (!instance)` to work, you can't do `var instance = {};` to initialize `instance`. Just leave off the initializer (or use a falsy value like `null` or `undefined` explicitly).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : ya, but first time when browser reads JS it will go inside return of IIFE and so it will not recognize 'instance' as it has never encountered this variable. So, what does it matter if I put it as {} or undefined or null. It should not even recognize the 'instance' word or variable till now (when 1st time browser enters the code).

Comment: No, it will go through the whole IIFE body.

Comment: @Deadpool - No, that's incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in a comment, the problem is that `instance` is initialized to `{}`, which is truthy, so `!instance` will never be true.

There's only **one** `instance` variable, created for the **one** call to your anonymous function. That's the whole point of having it, it tracks the singleton. So initialize it with a falsy value (or leave it with the default `undefined`, which is falsy):

```js
var a = ( function(){
 
  var instance = null;

  function init() {
     return {
      name: "rosy",
      age: 29,
      printName: function(){
        console.log(this.name)
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    getInstance: function(){
      if(!instance) {instance = init();}
      return instance;
    }
  }
})();

const first = a.getInstance();
console.log(first);
const second = a.getInstance();
console.log(second);
console.log(first === second); // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

That said, you only need all of this complexity if you want late initialization. Otherwise, just create the object:

```
var a = {
    instance = {
      name: "rosy",
      age: 29,
      printName: function(){
        console.log(this.name)
      }
    }
};
```

Then `a.instance` is the singleton. If you want it to be non-writable:

```
var a = Object.defineProperty({}, "instance", {
    value: {
      name: "rosy",
      age: 29,
      printName: function(){
        console.log(this.name)
      }
    }
});
```

(That will also be non-enumerable. If you want it to be enumerable, add `enumerable: true`.)

Or just:

```
var instance: {
  name: "rosy",
    age: 29,
    printName: function(){
      console.log(this.name)
    }
};
```

If you want *that* to be read-only, use `const` in any modern environment:

```
const instance: {
  name: "rosy",
    age: 29,
    printName: function(){
      console.log(this.name)
    }
};
```

---

In **all** of the above, remember that although you may have a singleton, and although the `instance` property/constant may be read-only, nothing about the object itself is immutable. Properties can be added, removed, changed, etc. To prevent *that*, use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

Answer (score 1):

If in case this can be a variety to  T.J. Crowder answer, You may create an instance once and save it to a variable, then every time the method is called, you may return that variable. I think `closure` plays a role here.

```js
var a = ( function(){
 
  var instance = {
      name: "rosy",
      age: 29,
      printName: function(){
        console.log(this.name)
      }
    };

  return {
    getInstance: function(){
      return instance;
    }
  }
})();
let b = a.getInstance();
let c = a.getInstance();
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
console.log( b === c )
```

Comment: That's an insightful suggestion, I never thought of singleton like that. could this be right? Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Yes, now you have a singleton that's pre-initialized. But really the only reason to have the `getInstance` function is lazy initialization. Otherwise, just make it a property on `a` as I shown in my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion, I will keep that in mind.